# Importing latex in HTML

Tags: html, latex

I am new to HTML.
What I want to do is to display a document written in LaTeX in HTML.

I have a document in LaTeX I have written for pdf, and I would like to display the content in HTML without copying the content in the HTML file.

I understand if I use MathJax, I can display LaTeX but it seems to me that this requires the LaTeX code to be written directly in the HTML document.

Is there a command like \input{} in HTML?

Comment: I do have my latex source file. But what I am trying to do is to use the same  file to make pdf and to display on HTML.

Comment: so I am looking for a way of  displaying by something like 
<embed src= document.tex>

Comment: So the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the simplest would be to convert latex/tex to html ?